# Command line output not showing up

Tags: c, command-line

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
      float value1 = 0, value2 = 0;
      char operator = 0;
      int lucky;
      float results[3] = {0};
      
      printf("Your name is %s and your lucky lottery number is %s\n\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
 
      printf("Type in your expression. \n");
      scanf ("%f %c %f",&value1,&operator,&value2);
      switch(operator) 
      {
        case '+':
          results[i] = value1 + value2;
          break;
        case '-':
          results[i] = value1 - value2;
          break;
        case '*':
          results[i] = value1 * value2;
          break;
        case '/':
          results[i] = value1 / value2;
          break;
        default:
          printf("Unknown Operator \n"); 
          return 0;
        }
     }
     for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
          printf("%s, your result %d is : %.2f\n", argv[1], i, results[i]);
          if (value1 == lucky || value2 == lucky){
              lucky = atoi(argv[2]);
              printf("\n%s, is your lucky day! %s is the lucky lottery number. Congratulations!", argv[1], argv[2]);
          }
     }
}
```

This code firsts ask the user to input their name and a number into the command line. Then it will ask them to enter 3 different expressions and the program will give the result. The output looks like this:

first we type in the command line something like: ./main.c tony 12

> Your name is tony and your lucky lottery number is 12
> Type in your expression.
> 12+3
> Type in your expression.
> 1*7
> Type in your expression.
> 1-1
>
> tony, your result 0 is : 15.00
> tony, your result 1 is : 7.00
> tony,  your result 2 is : 0.00

My problem is for the if statement in the print loop at the bottom, it's supposed to print a message saying that they acquired the lucky number if either the first or second value of the expression is the number inputted in the command line. How do I get it to print the message if the user entered the lucky number in either the first or second value of the expression? I converted argv[2] into an integer and stored it in the variable named 'lucky' and then did an if condition, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: you have to assign `lucky` before you compare it with `value1` and `value2`

Comment: You need to compare `value1` and `value2` with `lucky` in the first loop. When the second loop runs, those variables are just from the last expression.

Answer (score 0):

The check for the lucky number needs to be in the loop where you ask for the expressions, because you overwrite `value1` and `value2` each time through the loop.

To print the congratulations message, you can set a variable during the loop.

You need to assign `lucky` before you use it in this test.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    float value1 = 0, value2 = 0;
    char operator = 0;
    int lucky;
    int lucky_matched = 0;
    float results[3] = {0};

    lucky = atoi(argv[2]);
      
    printf("Your name is %s and your lucky lottery number is %d\n\n", argv[1], lucky);
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Type in your expression. \n");
        scanf ("%f %c %f",&value1,&operator,&value2);
        switch(operator) 
        {
        case '+':
            results[i] = value1 + value2;
            break;
        case '-':
            results[i] = value1 - value2;
            break;
        case '*':
            results[i] = value1 * value2;
            break;
        case '/':
            results[i] = value1 / value2;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown Operator \n"); 
            return 0;
        }
        if (value1 == lucky || value2 == lucky){
            lucky_matched = 1;
        }
    }

    if (lucky_matched) {
        printf("\n%s, is your lucky day! %s is the lucky lottery number. Congratulations!", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%s, your result %d is : %.2f\n", argv[1], i, results[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. However, is there any way for the 'congratulations' message to show at the end of all of the results instead of right after the expression?

Comment: You could put `value1` and `value2` in an array, and test them in the second loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer to set a variable during the first loop, and check it at the end.